# Calculate percentage and display result in div element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to work out the percentage amount saved between price and saleprice and display the result in a div. So far I have the following but it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calc()
{
    var price = 0;
    var saleprice = 0;
    var savingPercent = 0;

    price = Number(document.getElementById("price").value);
    saleprice = Number(document.getElementById("saleprice").value); 

    savingPercent =(((price - saleprice) / price) * 100).toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('savingPercent').innerHTML = "You have saved" +savingPercent+"% ";  
}
</script>

<div id="price">&pound;100</div>
<div id="saleprice">&pound;20</div>
<div id="savingPercent"></div>
```

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be working" is too vague. Try putting some breakpoints (in Chrome developer tools or similar) in your javascript, and inspect as it goes through the code.

Comment: You aren't calling your function anywhere. `function calc(){}` sort-of creates a machine called "calc", but that machine doesn't "turn on" until you type `calc()` somewhere after that.

Comment: where are you calling this...are you missing something

Comment: Hey even if you call calc() independently it wont work because your saleprice value is pound100 and you are trying to convert that to a number which is wrong

Comment: Also... div do not have the .value property you need to add innerText or innerHTML, and as @Geeky has mentioned you have a pound sign which makes your price and sales price NaNs

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code.

1. You're not calling the `calc` function anywhere
2. The elements with the ids `price` and `saleprice` are `HTMLDivElement`s originated from the `div` tags you placed in your code. They don't have a property named `value`. The correct property should be `textContent`.
3. Since your values have a `&pound;` character before the values themselves, you should take only the substring after it.

The snippet below is working as you expected.

```js
function calc() {
  var price = 0;
  var saleprice = 0;
  var savingPercent = 0;
  
  price = Number(document.getElementById("price").textContent.substring(1));
  saleprice = Number(document.getElementById("saleprice").textContent.substring(1)); 

  savingPercent =(((price - saleprice) / price) * 100).toFixed(0);
  document.getElementById('savingPercent').innerHTML = "You have saved " + savingPercent + "%";  
}
  
calc();
```

```html
<div id="price">&pound;100</div>
<div id="saleprice">&pound;20</div>
<div id="savingPercent"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, Ive taken advice from a few nd got it to work:

Answer (score 0):

div tags don't have value, you need to use innerHTML, like this:

```
price = Number(document.getElementById("price").innerHTML);
saleprice = Number(document.getElementById("saleprice").innerHTML);
```

and move £ outside of the div

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. There's lots of good advice here, I will keep working on it.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because `Number` only converts a numeric string to a number (e.g. `"300"` => `300`), it *does not* parse numeric values out of a mixed string (e.g. `Number("$500") === NaN`). You need to use a regular expression to parse the numeric value out:

```
price = document.getElementById("price").value;
saleprice = document.getElementById("saleprice").value; 

// remove non-numeric values and cast to a Number
price = Number(price.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
saleprice = Number(saleprice.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
```

Comment: Many thanks for your comments, I'm very new to javascript so will have to take some time to look at these.

Answer (score 0):

Like RobertAKARobin said, you are missing to call the function anywhere. Also you don't get the prices right.

Instead of `value` you need to get the `innerHTML`. And thus your browser can't parse a string with a Pund-sign, you need to substring that value.

And at last, you should parse the string to int by using `parseInt()`, like so:

```
var price = parseInt(document.getElementById("price").innerHTML.substr(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` or `textContent` is not right place for that even if You can do `slice` or `substr` - it's too complicated.

why not simply keep data in datasets? read about `data-*` attributes.

```html
<div id="price" data-value="100">&pound;100</div>
<div id="saleprice" data-value="20">&pound;20</div>
<div id="savingPercent"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function calc()
{
    var price = Number(document.getElementById("price").dataset.value);
    var saleprice = Number(document.getElementById("saleprice").dataset.value); 
    var savingPercent =(((price - saleprice) / price) * 100).toFixed(0);

    document.getElementById('savingPercent').innerHTML = "You have saved "+savingPercent+"%";  
}

// execute function when window totally loaded
window.onload = function() {
  // do something ...
  calc();
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider changing the markup for this
It is not working because your price and saleprice are  £ 100
£ 20 and you are trying to convert them to numbers which would result into NAN

check the following code snippet

```js
calc();
function calc()
{
    var price = 0;
    var saleprice = 0;
    var savingPercent = 0;

    price = Number(document.getElementById("price").innerHTML);
  price
    saleprice = Number(document.getElementById("saleprice").innerHTML); 
    savingPercent =(((price - saleprice) / price) * 100).toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('savingPercent').innerHTML = "You have saved" +savingPercent+"% ";  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>&pound;</span>
<span id="price">100</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>&pound;</span>
<span id="saleprice">20</span>
</div>

<div id="savingPercent"></div>
```

Another thing, I am calling calc() independently here , you might consider binding an event to trigger calc method

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help, I have taken tips from a few of you and got it to work with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() {

    var price = 0;
    var saleprice = 0;
    var savingPercent = 0;

    price = Number(document.getElementById("price").innerHTML);
    saleprice = Number(document.getElementById("saleprice").innerHTML); 

    savingPercent =(((price - saleprice) / price) * 100).toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('savingPercent').innerHTML = "You have saved " +savingPercent+"% ";  
}
</script>

<div>
  <span>&pound;</span>
  <span id="price">100</span>
</div>

<div>
    <span>&pound;</span>
    <span id="saleprice">20</span>
</div>

<div id="savingPercent"></div>
```

Although I have just realised I need to target classes not ID's. When I change to document.getElementsByClassName it stops working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() {

    var price = 0;
    var saleprice = 0;
    var savingPercent = 0;

    price = Number(document.getElementsByClassName("price").innerHTML);
    saleprice = Number(document.getElementsByClassName("saleprice").innerHTML); 

    savingPercent =(((price - saleprice) / price) * 100).toFixed(0);
    document.getElementsByClassName('savingPercent').innerHTML = "You have saved " +savingPercent+"% ";  
}
</script>

<div>
   <span>&pound;</span>
   <span class="price">100</span>
</div>

<div>
   <span>&pound;</span>
  <span class="saleprice">20</span>
</div>

<div class="savingPercent"></div>
```

Can anyone tell me why it wont work with classes when it was working fine with ID's. Thank you.